# Capture any sound that is played by soundboard without "What you hear" or similar device

Tags: c#, .net

There is a Total Recorder software that can record in "soundboard" mode and in "software" mode. If soundboard doen't provide "Stereo Mix" or "What you hear" devices, Total Recorder can capture any sound from the soundboard in "software" mode using its own playback and recording drivers. I need to write a program that captures sound in "software" mode. I suppose I need similar drivers that could pass every sound to my program. Are there any of those? Or is it possible to write these drivers on my own for a reasonable amount of time? Searching didn't help, I found info on "Stereo Mix", which is not supported in my case, and Virtual Audio Cable, but it needs setting in "VAC Control Panel" and to select "Virtual Audio Cable" in actually playing application. Requiring those additional steps from the user part is not acceptable in my case. Tried several demos - no one worked. But Total Recorder captures sound exactly how I need. How can I implement this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are reffering to is called Audio Loopback and its fairly simple to do on your own if you know how to program. Here is MSDN information on how to do it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316551.aspx

In addition, here is sample source code for a loopback program that your looking for: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matthew_van_eerde/archive/2008/12/16/sample-wasapi-loopback-capture-record-what-you-hear.aspx

The code is in C and not C# unfortunately.

Comment: I think it should be mentioned that the code is using WASAPI, which is only available since Vista, so no XP support.

Comment: @svick: Good spot. I didn't notice that till you just pointed it out

Comment: @svick Useful remark, thanks. It is OK to go without support of this functionality at Windows XP, at least for now.