# How to listen to audio coming from certain process and compare it to 5 second sound?

Tags: c#, winforms, audio

What i want to do is capture audio coming from some.exe all the time, check if the program outputs sound that i have already stored, say 5 second audio.

For example I capture some.exe saying  "You win" , save it in .wav or whatever. then start monitoring some.exe and if it says "You win" again, do something.

Comment: The input will never be the same twice. It will differ in amplitude, frequency components and length.  You would need to come up with some time warping similarity metric.

Comment: It takes the massively parallel computing hardware you have between your ears a good three years to learn this trick.  You can get a possible shortcut by using the System.Speech.Recognition namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API to intercept audio output of a specific process. You can either capture back a mix of audio generated by ALL applications on specific endpoint, or you have to get your hands dirty with complicated API hooking.

See also:

- [Is it possible to caputre the rendering audio session from another process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107368/is-it-possible-to-caputre-the-rendering-audio-session-from-another-process/14779632#14779632)
- [Is it possible to record sound played on the sound card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241352/is-it-possible-to-record-sound-played-on-the-sound-card/8243007#8243007)
- [Reading audio stream to output device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636688/reading-audio-stream-to-output-device/17637223#17637223)
- [Capture any sound that is played by soundboard without "What you hear" or similar device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526760/capture-any-sound-that-is-played-by-soundboard-without-what-you-hear-or-simila)